# Creating cat and dog objects and adding them to collection without repeating base class properties

Tags: .net, oop

I am populating a collection List from data from a database.  The database results contain both cats and dogs.

I want to do something like this

```
var animals = new List();

var animal = new Animal()
animal.Name = row["name"] //Name is a property in the base class Animal (shared by both cats and dogs)

if row["type"] == 1 //cat
   animal = (Cat)animal;
   animal.CanMeow = row["meow"];  // set property specific to cats
else
   animal = (Dog)animal;
   animal.Bark = row["bark"]; // set property specific to dogs
end if

animals.Add(animal);
```

How can I accomplish this in c# .net 4?

ty

Comment: Did you mean to use an non-generic list? or should that be `List<Animal>`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're doing it the wrong way. You are creating an `Animal` and trying to cast that to a derived class. That's not possible. You need to create an instance of the derived class and cast it to the base class.

```
List list = new List<Animal>();
Animal a = null;
if(row["type"]==1)
{
    Cat c = new Cat();
    a = (Animal)c;
    //cat specific assignments here
    c.CanMeow = row["CanMeow"];
}
else
{
    Dog d = new Dog();
    a = (Animal)d;
    //dog specific assignments here
}

//generic assignments here
a.Name=row["Name"]
list.Add(a);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use a scheme like this

```
private void PopulateAnimal(animal a, DataRow dr)
{
    animal.Name = row[NAME];
}


private void Something()
{ 
    //Read DB
    if (row[TYPE] == CAT){
          Cat c = new Cat();
          PopulateAnimal(c, row);

          //Cat properties
          c.CanMeow = row[CAN_MEOW];

          animals.Add(c);
    }else if (row[TYPE] == DOG){
          Dog d = new Dog();
          PopulateAnimal(d, row);

          //Dog properties
          d.CanBark = row[CAN_BARK];

          animals.Add(d);
    }else{
       //throw or whatever
    }
}
```

This allows you to put all the common property assignments in a single method and lets you call it from wherever its needed.

If you like you can move the `animals.Add` call to the `PopulateAnimal` method (and call it last).  This might me a little less code, but a little less clear as well.

Answer (score 0):

Syntax might be a bit off but here it goes:

```
List<Animal> animals = new List<Animal>();

var cats = from animal in animalTable.AsEnumerable()
where animal.Field<int>("type") == 1
select new Cat() { Name = animal.Field<string>("name"), CanMeow = animal.Field<bool>("meow") };

var dogs = from animal in animalTable.AsEnumerable()
where animal.Field<int>("type") != 1
select new Dpg() { Name = animal.Field<string>("name"), Bark = animal.Field<bool>("bark") };

animals.addRange(cats);
animals.addRange(dogs);
```